# XMLHttpRequest fails with HTTPS / MSIE 10 / POST / Lots of requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got some software that works well in a lot of cases, but fails badly with MSIE 10.  I've broken it down to the simplest test case I can, shown below.  XMLHttpRequest will sometimes work, but more often it will wait for 5 to 10 seconds (that times changes constantly) and then return with a status code 0.

It is only the **combination** of HTTPS & MSIE 10 & Lots of POST requests.  Changing any one of these will cause things to work again.

- Other browsers work fine, including MSIE 8.  It's not a server
  problem.  I can have 10 copies of the test program running at once on
  chrome with no issues.
- It's only HTTPS.  When I switch to HTTP everything works fine.  (The
  same server is listening to both ports, serving the same software.) 
  My temporary work around is showing people the HTTP address, but I
  don't like that.
- This only happens with a POST request.  When I change my test program
  to do a GET instead of a POST, everything works fine.  Unfortunately
  that's not an option for the real program.
- This only happens after a lot of continuous requests.  Often it will
  be fine for a few requests, then start failing.  Hitting refresh
  doesn't help.  It's like the browser, not my script, is having
  trouble.

Has anyone seen a problem like that?  Do you know how to fix it?

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>test</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT>
      <!--
  var count = 0;
  function addLine(line)
  {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerText = line;
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
  function my_main()
  {
    addLine("script started");
    scheduleRequest();
  }
  function scheduleRequest()
  {
    try
    {
      if (count < 50)
      {
        count++;
        //setTimeout(sendRequest, 1);
        sendRequest();
      }
      else
        addLine("Done!");
    } catch (err) {
        addLine("Exception in scheduleRequest():  " + err.message);
    }
  }
  function sendRequest()
  {
    try
    {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("POST","t.php?nocache="+Math.random(),true);
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        { 
          var success = (xmlhttp.responseText == "yes\n") && (xmlhttp.status == 200);
      var status = "#" + count + ":  ";
          if (success)
            status += "success.";
          else 
            status += "FAIL.  status=" + xmlhttp.status;
          addLine(status);
          scheduleRequest();
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.send("sequence=5");
    } catch (err) {
        addLine("Exception in sendRequest():  " +  err.message);
    }
  }
      -->
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY ONLOAD="my_main()">
    <div>Let's go!</div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Just curious if you look in the Network tab of the `F12` developer tools do you see all the requests (POSTs) go to your server? (e.g. do they all get submitted or are some missed?)

Comment: POST requests do not cache so the random number does not matter. Also random numbers can repeat so that can fail. ;)

Comment: Please also keep in mind that `.innerText` has compatibility issues: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04 (e.g. not supported in Firefox) the W3C `.textContent` of course isn't fully supported in IE either. :-P  In this case (a `div`) I'd just set the `.innerHTML` as it will work in all browsers consistently.

Comment: @scunliffe yes, I ran into that issue with the innerText in FireFox.  Please keep in mind that this is a very stripped down version of the real program.  The real program uses widgets and such to display the data.  My concern is the network problem.

Comment: @epascarello thank you, but I needed those random numbers for another version of the test.  I tried several versions of this test program to figure out exactly where the problem was.  One version used GET instead of POST.  In any case, I don't think that's the source of my troubles.

Comment: Any chance you can post the headers sent in from IE10 to your server and the response headers returned from your server? The code works as is for me in my tests on IE10.

Comment: @scunliffe should be easy when my tester gets back tomorrow.  It's hard supporting so many different browsers!  All of the ones I have on my computer work just fine.

Comment: Here's a "real" example of the problem.  https://secure.trade-ideas.com/mapreduce/TIProWeb/TIPro.html  You can log in as DEMO / DEMO and see the connection.  This is where we first saw the problem.  I wrote the javascript code above to isolate the problem.

Comment: @scunliffe https://plus.google.com/115277326832437462580/posts/WW7APDk9Try Here are screenshots of the network panel, headers sent, and headers received.  I'm a bit disturbed by the fact that it works so well on one IE10 instance, but not on another.  I'm used to problems that are browser specific.  If there's something else, I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering with the "Aborted" Status if IE is trying to be helpful... and auto-cancelling high volume requests... to "help" the user by not hammering the server and allowing it time to respond. It would be interesting to set thresholds on the requests... e.g. every 5 seconds, then every 4, every 3, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25 and see at what point IE stops sending them.